# "Use default value" with category in AvS/FastSimpleImport : how?

Tags: magento-1.9, import, importexport, avs-fastsimpleimport

I'm trying to import a category array with [AvS/FastSimpleImport](https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport) where:

Index 0: the default scope
Index 1: values for the `it` store
Index 2: values for the `en` store

The goal is to set `Use default value` for the `###EMPTY###` values.

This is my array, and it works like a charm:

```
‌‌$arrAvS
‌array (
  0 => 
  array (
    '_root' => 'Default Category',
    'is_active' => 'yes',
    'include_in_menu' => 'yes',
    'available_sort_by' => NULL,
    'default_sort_by' => 'position',
    'display_mode' => 'static block only',
    'code_category' => 'D',
    '_category' => 'My category',
    'url_key' => 'my-cat',
    'meta_title' => 'DEFAULT: meta-title',
    'meta_description' => 'DEFAULT: meta-descr',
    'description' => 'DEFAULT: descr',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    '_store' => 'it',
    'name' => 'IT: name',
    'url_key' => 'it-slug',
    'meta_title' => 'ITA: meta-title',
    'meta_description' => 'ITA: meta-descr',
    'description' => 'ITA: descr',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    '_store' => 'en',
    'meta_title' => 'EN: meta-title',
    'meta_description' => 'EN: meta-descr',
    'name' => 'EN: name',
    'url_key' => 'en-slug',
    'description' => 'EN: description',
  ),
)
```

Again, this works as expected.

**The problem occurs  when I want to set the store value to `Use default value`**. For example, i change the second array from `'name' => 'EN: name',` to `'name' => '###EMPTY###'` (`description` also). In this scenario, the name|description fields in the EN storeview simply get set to empty

[image: Screenshot]

The importing code is:

```
$import = Mage::getModel('fastsimpleimport/import');
$import->processCategoryImport($arrAvS);
```

Admin config:

[image: Screenshot]

The store is a july-SUPEE patched Magento ver. 1.9.2.4.

AvS is 0.7.1.

Any help is greatly appreciated

---

One more example:

````

```
    $data = array();
    $data[] = array(
        '_root' => 'Default Category',
        '_category' => 'Myyy Category',
        'description' => 'Myyy Category Description',
        'is_active' => 'yes',
        'include_in_menu' => 'yes',
        'meta_description' => 'Myyy Category Meta',
        'available_sort_by' => 'position',
        'default_sort_by' => 'position',
    );

    $data[] = array(
        '_store' => 'en',
        'name' => 'I don't want to put a custom text here, must use default',
        'description' => 'Myyy Category EN DESCR'
    );


    $this->import
        ->processCategoryImport($data);
```

````

To use default for `name`, I changed the second element to:

'name' => false

nope, still do not use default, displays empty text

'name' => null,

nope

'name' => Mage::getStoreConfig('fastsimpleimport/general/symbol_for_clear_field')

nope

I'm fresh out of ideas, thanks

Answer (score 0):

"Use default value" function is base on product attribute value is  bool false.
 like below:

```
$product->setName(false)
```

Good luck!

Additional:

For category import, extension do no deal with ###EMPTY### such case, and it also does not implement standard model method. You can rewrite the function  *AvS_FastSimpleImport_Model_Import_Entity_Category->_saveCategoryAttributes* like below

```
   protected function _saveCategoryAttributes(array $attributesData)
{
    foreach ($attributesData as $tableName => $data) {
        $tableData = array();
        foreach ($data as $entityId => $attributes) {

            foreach ($attributes as $attributeId => $storeValues) {
                foreach ($storeValues as $storeId => $storeValue) {
                    if (!is_null($storeValue)) {
                        $tableData[] = array(
                            'entity_id' => $entityId,
                            'entity_type_id' => $this->_entityTypeId,
                            'attribute_id' => $attributeId,
                            'store_id' => $storeId,
                            'value' => $storeValue
                        );
                    } else {
                        // change start
                        $this->_connection->delete($tableName,array(
                            'entity_id' => $entityId,
                            'entity_type_id' => $this->_entityTypeId,
                            'attribute_id' => $attributeId,
                            'store_id' => $storeId,
                        )
                        // change end
                        );
                }

                }
            }
        }
        $this->_connection->insertOnDuplicate($tableName, $tableData, array('value'));
    }
    return $this;
}
```

That will make ###EMPTY### work to use default value for category import.

Comment: As you can read, I'm using an array and not an object. I tried `'name' => false`  but didn't work.